# Updated Windows Terminal and now Ubuntu won't load. process exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-terminal

Initially posted to the Unix \ linux stack exchange and was pointed here instead.

I recently updated Windows Terminal from 1.2.X to 1.12.X and the Ubuntu install refuses to run, giving the error `[process exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)]`. The older Ubuntu-18.04 runs fine however.

Entry in settings

```
    {
        "guid": "{2c4de342-38b7-51cf-b940-2309a097f518}",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "Ubuntu",
        "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"
    }
```

Any ideas on this one?

Command line options tried

- C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu
- C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu
- wsl.exe -d Ubuntu <- this copied from `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-18.04`

[image: Background - Windows Terminal & Foreground - Ubuntu terminal]

Comment: What is the connection between Windows Terminal and WSL?

Comment: @harrymc it's because I'm running the WSL Ubuntu terminal through Windows Terminal. If I run the independent Ubuntu terminal, it works.

Comment: @AlistairHardy - Can you provide the relevant information from your profile json for Windows Terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is detailed in the bug-report
[Unable to launch WSL Ubuntu - The system cannot find the file specified. #12474](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12474).

The workaround there was to change the commandline to:

```
<path_to>/wsl.exe ~ -d Ubuntu.<Version>
```

Comment: No joy for me I'm afraid

Comment: Another workaround in this post was to change the starting directory to `%USERPROFILE%` or something near.

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` worked!

Comment: @AlistairHardy Great to hear that worked.  I'm curious, though, since I *think* that would mean that Windows Terminal is setting the default path to something that WSL can't handle.  When you start Command Prompt or PowerShell from Windows Terminal, what directory do they start in?

Comment: CMD & Powershell start in c:\Users\USERNAME & Ubuntu is starting in /mnt/c/Users/USERNAME

Answer (score 5):

1. Click on arrow down on upper tab bar
2. Select Ubuntu Profile on left menu
3. Find Starting Directory option
4. Overwrite to %USERPROFILE%
5. Save

[image: Annotated screenshot of Settings dialog, showing steps]

Comment: Thanks for editing I wasn't able to put the image directly

Answer (score 3):

So in my case

1. Open PowerShell terminal
2. Stop the virtual machine by executing the following command in PowerShell:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

3. Reopen Ubuntu terminal and it ran smoothly.

I hope it will help some of you!

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

- First, delete the existing Ubuntu profile (back up `settings.json` if you want), exit Windows Terminal, and restart.  Windows Terminal should detect the Ubuntu installation and recreate the profile automatically.  See if the newly autogenerated one works.

If it doesn't:

- Start PowerShell and try from there:

  ```
  wsl -l -v # Sanity check the installations themselves
  wsl ~ -d Ubuntu
  wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu
  wsl ~ -d Ubuntu -e bash --noprofile --norc
  ```

  Does `wsl -l -v` show the correct profile?  If so, do any of the other commands work?  If the `wsl ~ -d Ubuntu` doesn't work but the other two do, then it's likely something in your bash startup config that is causing the issue.

If none of that helps:

- Was there any `/etc/wsl.conf` file in the Ubuntu instance?  Did it have a `Command=` line by any chance that could be failing?

Comment: wsl.conf only has `generateResolvConf = false` in it. Tried editing the settings.json as you said and that's had no luck. The `wsl` commands all worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you I tried everything else and the only thing that worked for me was adding -e bash, I have no idea why it's needed (shouldn't be), but ever since adding that it started working

Comment: @neokyle Glad to hear that it helped.  Was it the `-e bash` alone that worked or the `--noprofile --norc` as well?  If the former, then it sounds like the user shell may be changed.  If the later, then there's something wrong in the startup files.  Either way, we can troubleshoot from there.

Comment: -e bash was all I needed to add, the weird thing is `sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER` suggests that my shell was configured to use /bin/bash, and I don't recall changing it. Only thing I can think of is that maybe WSL has some other location to determine shell. The only other customization I have is /etc/wsl.conf sets systemd=true

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue
for me changing the executable path worked.  [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4MxE.png)

from

> C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04

to

> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04

Comment: How is this different from accepted answer?

Comment: accepted answer didn't work for me

Comment: this worked for me!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and found that the drive letter of my disk had changed (to E:). Reverting it back (to D:) and rebooting helped resolve this wsl issue.

Answer (score 0):

similar issue:

1. ubuntu run istelf fine.
2. ubuntu dont run from "windows terminal" // error: [process exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)]

fix:

1. open terminal
2. terminal setting
3. select ubuntu profile.
4. Right hand pane hange command line executable path to folowing
   C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe ~ -d Ubuntu
   or
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe ~ -d Ubuntu.
5. save profile, run again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [The author's question was caused by a bug that has since been fixed since it was asked six months ago.](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12249#issuecomment-1198547733)